# Which life cycle method called in ionic when a modal dialog got dismissed

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a `component A` from component A i am calling a Modal dialog when i am dismissing the `modal dialog` i want to capture the event in component A . But it seems there is no event triggered in `component A` . So far i tried with logging inside ionic life cycle methods Any hint would be highly appreciated ..

Here i dismiss the modal dialog by `this.navCtrl.pop()`

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    alert("ionViewDidEnter")

  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    alert("ionViewWillLeave")

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    alert("ionViewWillEnter")

  }

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    alert("ionViewDidLeave")

  }
  ionViewWillUnload() {
     alert("ionViewWillUnload")

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    alert("ionViewDidLoad")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this.

```
 let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('Anymodal');
    modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
    // Call back logic here       
});
modal.present();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take modal reference after creating the modal dialog like

```
let modalDialog = this.modalCtrl.create(ComponentA);
```

Then you have to handle onDidDismiss event of modal reference like

```
modalDialog.onDidDismiss = ((data) => { //your action after dismiss }})
```

And in modal dialog components, you have to call dismiss like

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(<data you want to pass>);
```

For more reference you can look here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-get-data-from-modal/105959

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers alluded, there are no lifecycle events triggered in the parent as it's not mutated, the modal appears atop it and then is dismissed from it, leaving the parent unaffacted, but you can trigger the dismiss function from within the parent to talk to your parent so to speak.

For Ionic 4 & 5 you declare your properties into the dismiss function inside of the component TS for your modal, such as:

```
this.modal.dismiss({
    category_selected: this.exampleVariable
});
```

Then over on your parent, you would specify the onDidDismiss promise with `then` ie:

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // { category_selected: foo }
});
```